# How do I change the color of a string that I display in a textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I am working on a chat application wherein I need the sender's and recipient's names to be highlighted on each chat message that is sent or received along with the respective time stamp. I have a textbox say 'txtclient' and I am throwing all the sender and receiver messages to this textbox. Since all the text is being displayed here, I cannot set the textbox's forecolor since it will be applied to all the text in it. kindly help. Here is the string whose color I want to be different or highlighted:

```
private void newThreadClientChat()
{
    SetText (DateTime.Now.ToString() + " : " + clientgetsetname + " : " + clientgetset + "\r\n");
}
```

Comment: What is SetText method ?

Comment: Is that a `RichTextBox`? If yes, you can apply font color for specific region.

Comment: Is this a TextBox or a RichTextBox? Is this Windows Forms, WPF, something else?

Comment: I am using windows forms and it is a textbox and not a rich textbox. I tried using a rich text box. How exactly do i use it to change only a part of it? Specially when I want the string to be colored?
@puko : its just a method to set the strings.

Comment: I want this whole part to be colored:  DateTime.Now.ToString() + " : " + clientgetsetname + " : "

Comment: Texboxes can only show 1 color. You change things in a RTB by 1) selecting them and 2) changing the selection's properties, e.g. SelectionForecolor = newcolor or SelectedText = newText

Comment: @TaW : i tried that! It doesnt change only a part of the text.

Comment: Yes it will if (and only if) you first select the part you want to change! For this you need to set the SelectionStart and the SelectionLength. Can be a little tricky but if you know in advance it will work just fine. (Also __NEVER__ change the Text, only use appendText or SelectedText!!)

Comment: @SwatiVerma If you've tried that, post the code  which doesn't work.